# Can we map an array to a integer?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stl

I came to know that we can map a vector and an integer.  I mean suppose we make `map<vector<int>,int>` mp.  Now suppose i make a `vector`, `vector<int> vec`. Suppose I push `2,3,4,5` in `vec`. Then by doing `++mp[vec]`, I will create an map between`vector {2,3,4,5}` and `1`. 
Now suppose in same `vec`, I erase all the data and then I push `11,12,13,14`. Now ifIi do `++mp[vec]` then an map between `vector {11,12,13,14}` and `1` will be created.
Now finally suppose I again erase all the data in `vec` and make `vector {2,3,4,5}` and I do `++mp[vec]`.  The map between `{2,3,4,5}` and `1` is changed to `{2,3,4,5}` and `2`.
Hence we have two maps in `mp`. First `({2,3,4,5},2)` and the second `({11,12,13,14},1)`.

Can we do similarly will arrays also? I mean I create an map between array and integer and for different arrays i get different map?

I tried to make between integer array and integer by `map<int[],int> mp`. Then I made an variable `int v[10]` . When I did `++mp[v]`, it gave an error.

Then I tried another method. I created map, `map<int * , int > mp`, but it was giving  wrong results. I mean it was not really storing maps between array and integer.I think it was storing map between pointer and integer.

Is it possible to create map between array in integer, I mean suppose I have an array of size 10, let `int v[10]` and I fill `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10` in it. When I do `++mp[v]`, a map between `array {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}` and `1` gets created. 
 Now if in same `array v`, I change values to `{11,12,13,14,5,6,7,8,9,10}` and I do `++mp[v]`, then a map between `{11,12,13,14,5,6,7,8,9,10}` and `1` gets created.  Now if finally in same variable `v` I store `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}` and then do `++mp[v]`, map between `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}` and `1` changes to `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}` and `2`.

This is my first question .I may be not asking perfectly .I welcome any comments or suggestions .

Comment: Try with `std::array`...

Comment: you do multiple wrong assumptions here. i suggest you read about std::map, operator [] or std::map, requirement to key type of map (operator < for key type in particular)

Comment: @AndrewKashpur the code works perfectly fine with `map<vector<int>,int>`, since `operator<` is defined.

Comment: Using large objects as map keys is generally a bad idea/design flaw. Is there any problem you are trying to solve with this, or is this question just out of curiosity?

Comment: People here generally do not care whether the question is related to competitive coding as long as it follows the rules for how to ask. However, there are a lot of bad questions coming from competitive coding backgrounds: People frequently just dump the task's text, or paste tons of terribly written code (there are many **awful** practices in competitive coding, mind you), or have made no attempt at debugging their code, or all of the above. But we still encourage good questions (and yours is doing fine for a first question)! (Edit: Replying to a now-deleted comment)

Comment: @MaxLanghof  It was not related to awful practice , i mean you can get what i am saying .It was already solved problem (one year back) .I can provide link if you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of a [raw array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array).  You can use

```
int main()
{
    std::map<std::array<int, 10>, int> mp;
    std::array v = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}; // this line requires C++17.  
    // If you don't have that use std::array<int, 10> v instead
    ++mp[v];
    v = {11,12,13,14,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    ++mp[v];
    v = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    ++mp[v];
    // now mp has ({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}, 2) and ({11,12,13,14,5,6,7,8,9,10}, 1) in it
}
```

Comment: Thanks . Is it necessary to define size of arrays ? I mean can i create a map variable mp between arrays and integers , where i can create map between {1,2} and 1 as well as {1,2,3} and 1 .Will map<std :: array<int> , int > will do it ?

Comment: @williamson No.  The key has to be the same type, and with arrays the size is part of the type.  You'll need a `std::vector` if you want that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can simply by using `std::array`:

```
std::map< std::array<int,10>, int> mp;
++mp[{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}];
++mp[{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11}];
```

**Warning** The inner workings of `map` creates a sorted tree of `pair<key,value>` objects. Thus not only do you have to keep these large keys (in this case `array<int,10>` or `vector<int>`) in memory, but also most operations (insertion, finding in particular) require O(log(n)) comparisons between keys. Now, comparing keys of 10 integers may cost up to ten times more than a single comparison.

Comment: Thanks . Is it necessary to define size of arrays  ? I mean can i create a map variable mp between arrays and integers , where i can create map between {1,2} and 1 as well as {1,2,3} and 1 .Will map<std :: array<int> , int > will do it ?

Comment: The number of elements of `std::array` is a compile-time constant (template parameter). If you want a variable number of elements, you need a run-time parameter that controls that. This is naturally provided by `std::vector`. Ordinary arrays often decay into pointers and any information about their size is lost.

Comment: @williamson Map keys need to be of same type for all instances stored. `std::array<int, 2>` and `std::array<int, 3>` are totally unrelated types (apart from sharing same interface), so no, you cannot. Similarly, `int[2]` and `int[3]` are of different types as well...

Comment: @Walter Can you please your warning part more  , i mean does using this is bad design .If yes it there nay better way to do it ?

Comment: @williamson Without knowing what you are trying to achieve in the end, we cannot really tell you if a better way exists or what it might be.

Comment: @MaxLanghof What Walter is trying to say in line "comparing keys of 10 integers may cost up to ten times more than a single comparison." . I mean it is obvious that doing something 10 times will cost 10 times more than doing once .I guess i missed something

Comment: @williamson There may be a better algorithm or approach for your problem than creating a map from integer arrays to single integers. Or, if there is no alternative to that, you could e.g. store the arrays in wrappers that avoid copying all the data around and/or provide a faster comparison mechanism. `std::shared_ptr` would be such a wrapper. But what might be a good idea in one use case might be terrible in another - there is no universal best solution.